# Selected value in dropdown not appearing after validation codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have select-box and some textboxes in a from. On form submit after validation how can I keep that earlier selected value to the select box.? I am using code Igniter validation classes. All other validations are working
I am new to CodeIgniter please help me.

here is my code

Controler  :

```
<?php

class Bank_branch extends CI_Controller {
            public function __construct(){
                  parent::__construct();
                  $data['row'] = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                  $this->load->library('form_validation');
                  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div id="errorDiv">', '</div>');
                  $this->load->model('bank_branch_model');
                  $this->load->model('banks_model');
              }

              function index()
              {               
                  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
                   {    
                        $data['row'] = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                        $this->load->view('header',$data);

                        $data['result'] = $this->bank_branch_model->all_bank_branches();
                        $this->load->view('settings_sidebar');
                        $this->load->view('bank_branch_view',$data);    
                        $this->load->view('footer'); 
                    }
                   else
                   {
                     //If no session, redirect to login page
                     $this->load->helper('url');
                      redirect('login/','refresh');
                   }
              } 

              function bank_branch_form()
              {
                        $data['row'] = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                        $this->load->view('header',$data);
                        $data['banks'] = $this->banks_model->all_banks();
                        $this->load->view('settings_sidebar');
                        $this->load->view('bank_branch_add',$data);
                        $this->load->view('footer'); 
              }


              function bank_branch_insert() 
              {                         
                    $data['title'] = 'Bank Branch Insertion Form';  
                    $bank_name = $this->input->post('sel_bank_name');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sel_bank_name', 'Bank Name', 'required|callback_select_validate');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_place_details', 'Place Details', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_ifsc_code', 'IFSC Code', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_contact_no1', 'Contact No 1', 'trim|xss_clean|min_length[10]|max_length[15]');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_contact_no2', 'Contact No 2', 'trim|xss_clean|min_length[10]|max_length[15]');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email');
                    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
                    {
                        $data['row'] = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                        $this->load->view('header',$data);
                        $data['banks'] = $this->banks_model->all_banks();
                        $data['result'] = $this->bank_branch_model->all_bank_branches();
                        $this->load->view('settings_sidebar');
                        $this->load->view('bank_branch_add',$data); 
                        $this->load->view('footer'); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->bank_branch_model->insert_bank_branch();
                        redirect('bank_branch', 'refresh');
                    }
              }

            function select_validate($bank_name)
            {
                 if($bank_name=="none")
                    {$this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'Please Select Your Branch.');
                    return false;}
                else 
                    {   return true;    }
            }
}
    ?>
```

View:

```
<div class="main_content">
    <div class="table_top">
        <span class="table_title">Add Bank Branch</span>
        <span class="add_record_btn">
        <a href="javascript:history.back()" title="Close"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/assets/img/icons/back-button.png"  /></a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_open('bank_branch/bank_branch_insert'); ?>
        <table width="769" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="191" height="41">Bank</td>
                    <td width="241">
                    <select  class="armr_text_box" id="sel_bank_name" name="sel_bank_name" >
                            <option value="none">-Select-</option>
                            <?php
                                foreach($banks as $bank):
                            ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $bank['bank_id']; ?>"><?php echo $bank['bank_name']; ?></option>
                            <?php
                                endforeach; 
                            ?>                          
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td width="321"><?php echo form_error('sel_bank_name'); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="56">Place Details</td>
                    <td><textarea  class="armr_text_area"  id="txt_place_details" name="txt_place_details"  onkeyup="ucfirst(this)"><?php echo set_value('txt_place_details'); ?></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td> <?php echo form_error('txt_place_details'); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="43">IFSC Code</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="armr_text_box" id="txt_ifsc_code" name="txt_ifsc_code"  value="<?php echo set_value('txt_ifsc_code'); ?>"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo form_error('txt_ifsc_code'); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="41">Contact No 1</td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="armr_text_box" id="txt_contact_no1" name="txt_contact_no1" value="<?php echo set_value('txt_contact_no1'); ?>" />
                  </td>
                  <td><?php echo form_error('txt_contact_no1'); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="45">Contact No 2</td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="armr_text_box" id="txt_contact_no2" name="txt_contact_no2"  value="<?php echo set_value('txt_contact_no2'); ?>"/>
                  </td>
                  <td><?php echo form_error('txt_contact_no2'); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="44">Email</td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="armr_text_box" id="txt_email" name="txt_email"  value="<?php echo set_value('txt_email'); ?>"/>
                  </td>
                  <td> <?php echo form_error('txt_email'); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td height="43"></td>
                  <td><input  type="submit" value="Submit" class="armr_submit_btn" />
                  <input  type="reset" value="Cancel" class="armr_cancel_btn"  /></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
         <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try this `<option value="">-Select-</option>` remove value="none" to blank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `set_select()` helper function in CI.
Link is [Here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

For Example:

```
<select  class="armr_text_box" id="sel_bank_name" name="sel_bank_name" >
                            <option value="none">-Select-</option>
                            <?php
                                foreach($banks as $bank):
                            ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $bank['bank_id']; ?>" <?php echo set_select('sel_bank_name',  $bank['bank_id']); ?>><?php echo $bank['bank_name']; ?></option>
                            <?php
                                endforeach; 
                            ?>                          
                    </select>//the ser
```

Comment: <?php echo set_select('sel_bank_name',  $bank['bank_id']); ?>    worked.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<select  class="armr_text_box" id="sel_bank_name" name="sel_bank_name" >
    <option value="none">-Select-</option>
    <?php
        $sel_bank_name = set_value('sel_bank_name');
        foreach($banks as $bank):
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $bank['bank_id']; ?>" <?php $sel_bank_name == $bank['bank_id'] ? "selected":"" ?>><?php echo $bank['bank_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
        endforeach; 
    ?>                          
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

`$BankList['none'] = '-Select-';
foreach($banks as $bank):
    $BankList[$bank['bank_id']] = $bank['bank_name'];
endforeach;
echo form_dropdown('sel_bank_name',$BankList,set_value('sel_bank_name')," class='armr_text_box' id='sel_bank_name' ");`